# How to update-database Programmatically in EntityFramework Codefirst?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

i am writing a simple `CMS` over ASP.NET MVC framework (for college final project).my problem is with module's data-migration strategy.as each module will update the database schema when it is installed , a database migration mechanism must be implemented in module installation system.ok , `data-migration` in entity framework is already there (thanks to MS) , but the migration commands run in package manager console.is there any way to run a `Data-Migration` code Programmatically?
any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This class exposes the EF migrations in code:

[System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.103).aspx)

In EF, migrations work on a whole database though - not modular parts of one.

---

Just found this class too:

[System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 21):

If you've enabled the automatic migrations in *Package Manager Console* you can use the following code in an init section of your app (e.g. in *SimpleMembershipInitializer*):

```
var migratorConfig = new Migrations.Configuration();
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(migratorConfig); 
dbMigrator.Update();
```

Where *Migrations.Configuration* is the migration configuration class placed in your project into your namespace (*YourProjectNamespace.Migrations*).

If you use it programmatically you should at first turn off the EF initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDBContext>(null);
```

The thing is the programmatic update creates a database if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't have Automatic Migrations enabled and this code still seems to work for me.

Comment: Maybe it is question of version. When I posted the answer I was using EF 4.0.