# Entity framework programmatically update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget-package

I have a c# project in which i created an Entity Framework Context and all the DBSets.
I can create and migrate the db through the Package Manager Console. What i want to do, is do the same thing but without input commands in the Package Manager Console. If it's possible, i want to simulate those commands by code; for example clicking a button i can call an equivalent instruction of `Update-Database -Force`.
Is it possible to do this thing or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can find one answer for you question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342516/how-to-update-database-programmatically-in-entityframework-codefirst) Migrations library are exposed through a set o libraries.

Comment: It's not what i'm searching for because i haven't a direct access to the Context. I need to simulate exactly what Package Manager Console did.