# EF6 Multi-tenant (multi database) Web App - code first migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, multi-tenant

Surprisingly I can't find anyone with this particular scenario so hear goes. I'm developing a SAAS style MVC/EF web app. I want to offer each customer their own sub-domain name and isolated database, the domain name will determine the name/connection string for the application's single EF context. So when each customer signs up I'll spin up a new database and redirect them to their sub-domain to log in.

However when I switch connection name at runtime, code first migrations do not fire and provision the new database up to the latest version. I'm guessing this is because EF will only fire migrations once per context type for the lifetime of the app. Any suggestions? could I somehow manually fire migrations at application start for all registered sub-domains/databases?

Comment: You basically need to apply migrations programmatically. See [this][1] and [this][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692584/ef-5-code-first-create-a-new-database-and-run-all-migrations-programatically
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342516/how-to-update-database-programmatically-in-entityframework-codefirst

Comment: That's done it! I've switched off the default setInitializer() call in global.asax and iterating over my databases to manually initialize them...            foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connectionString in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
            {
                var configuration = new LeaderBoardConfiguration { TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString.Name) };
                var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
                migrator.Update();
            }       Thanks for the pointer.