# Adding a new property in Identity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

First, the IdentityModels.cs looked like this : 
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I changed this file to this :

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());
        }
    }
}
```

I also added Email to RegisterViewModel in AccountViewModel.cs.

I also changed AccountController to this :

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email};
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

When I click register, it fails at this line :

```
 var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Saying this :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Email'.
>   Why am I getting this error? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Did you update your database schema after making the changes? It seems that the changes in model are not reflected in your database.

Comment: @PythaLye I'm using this :  `Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>());` so, the database should be dropped and created after I add Email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open up nuget console and type:

```
update-database -force
```

before that make sure you have automatic migrations turned on.
you can turn it on by doing

```
enable-migrations
```

Comment: I'm dropping and recreating the database in my code, shouldn't it work?

Comment: That command worked! But I'm wondering why.. Why do I need it? Thanks

Comment: because it seems that you are not updating the schema just by dropping db.

Comment: you can do it by a helper class. here is the question which is asked some where else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342516/how-to-update-database-programmatically-in-entityframework-codefirst